# SQL: Adding up a particular ProductID that was purchased with another ProductID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, visual-studio

[image: MSORDERLINE]

[image]

I'm trying to find which products have the most add-ons (syrup, espresso shot etc). How would I do this? I can find individual sales, but how would I add an expresso to a coffee drink?

```
Select p.ProductName, TotalADDON = SUM(Quantity)
From MSProducts p, MSOrderline o
where p.ProductID = o.ProductID
Group By p.ProductName
```

This is the best I've come up with, but it adds up each coffee bought individually with add-ons. Add-on ProductID are 1444 and 1445. Any help or walkthrough would be greatly appreciated!

The results that I am looking for is...

**ProductID** **TotalAddOn**

1451___________ 1

1452___________ 0

1453___________ 0

1461___________ 0

1462___________ 0

1463___________ 0

1471___________ 0

1472___________ 0

1473___________ 0

1481___________ 6

1482___________ 0

1483___________ 0

1491___________ 0

1492___________ 0

1493___________ 2

Of Course there is more data, but with the data given this would be the result.

Comment: what sort of result are you looking at?

Comment: If you look at PurchaseID 321, there was 2 add-ons purchased for 1493. Then Purchase ID has 324 has 6 add-ons purchased for 1481.

Comment: you are just wanting to display the main order and the # of add-ons on top of it?

Comment: Each ProductID (ProductName and ProductID) with the # of add-ons

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll have it updated in 10 minutes

Comment: Alright I gave the expected results for the data present in this question. There is more data, but I didn't want to take up all the space. Though, if two different productID's such as 1462 and 1463 were purchased and 1 1444 was with that PurchaseID then both 1462 and 1463 would have +1 TotalAddOn

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Get number of add-ons purchased 
> 2) Get main beverage on orders
>   with add-ons only
>  3) display products purchased with add-ons

```
select x.ProductID,x.ProductName, sum(x.TotalAddOnsperPurchase) TotalQty from

(   Select p.ProductName,p.ProductID,o.PurchaseID,
    (select sum(quantity) from MSOrderline l where l.productID in (1444,1445) and l.PurchaseID = o.PurchaseID)  TotalAddOnsperPurchase   -- to sum quantity of add-ons
    From MSProducts p
    inner join MSOrderline o on
    p.ProductID = o.ProductID
    where
    p.productID not in ('1444','1445')   -- exclude this so to only display main beverage
) x

where x.TotalAddOnsperPurchase > 0 -- remove this line if you want to display everything
group by x.ProductID,x.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something related to the total quantity of *other* products in an order, for each product.

You can get that for each order by doing:

```
select p.purchaseId, p.productId, sum(o.quantity) as otherQuantity
from MSProducts p join
     MSOrderline o
     on p.PurchaseId = o.PurchaseId and
        p.ProductId <> o.ProductId
group by p.purchaseId, p.productId;
```

Then, if you wanted the average per order, here is one way:

```
select productId, avg(otherQuantity) as avgOthers, count(*) as numOrders
from (select p.purchaseId, p.productId, sum(o.quantity) as otherQuantity
      from MSProducts p join
           MSOrderline o
           on p.PurchaseId = o.PurchaseId and
              p.ProductId <> o.ProductId
      group by p.purchaseId, p.productId
     ) pp
group by productId;
```